# Are there any method that perform same as using "column stack" in numpy PYTHON

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, hdf5

I am using Python 2.7. My system is running Window Vista, 32 bits.

I have a piece of code that reads radiance, Latitude and Longitude and an image file(in hdf extension). And then try to perform approximated nearest neighbor and map it. But when it tries to do the approximated nearest neighbor, it gives me Memory Error.

The hdf file alone is 4.70 MB, which seems like the size is not too large.

Here is my code:

```
if __name__=="__main__":

    filename = ... ( the hdf file I have)      
    cumData, z = readAIRS_L1_VIS(filename)

    x, y = get_lat_lon(filename)  

    x0, xn = int(x.min()+1), int(x.max())
    y0, yn = int(y.min()+1), int(y.max())

    ncol = xn - x0 + 1
    nrow = yn - y0 + 1

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x0, xn+1), np.arange(y0, yn+1))
    img = interp_knn(np.column_stack((x.ravel(), y.ravel())),
            z.ravel(), np.column_stack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel())))
    img.shape = (nrow, ncol)
```

Then my functions and imports are:

```
from pyhdf.SD import SD
import scipy as sc
import numpy as np
import pylab, os
import pyproj as proj
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import scikits.ann as ann

def readAIRS_L1_VIS(filename,variable=None):
    allz=[]
    """
    function
        read hdf file for AIR Level 1B VIS
    input : AIRS HDF file
    input : variables parameter (optional, default = radiances)

    returns dictionary with data and meta
    """

    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        raise "Invalid Filepath"
    reader = SD(filename)
    aVariables = reader.datasets().keys()
    if variable==None:
        variable = 'radiances'
    elif variable in aVariables:
        pass
    else:
        raise "Invalid Variable Specified"

    data = reader.select(variable).get()
    #data = np.array(data)
    allz.append(data)
    outDict = {'Variable':variable,'filename':filename.split('/')[-1],'data':data}
    return outDict,np.vstack(allz)
```

This is the def get_lat_lon:

```
def get_lat_lon(path):
    allx = []
    ally = []
    reader = SD(path)
    lat = reader.select('Latitude').get()
    lon = reader.select('Longitude').get()    
    x,y = Proj(lon,lat)
    x /= 1000.0
    y /= 1000.0

    allx.append(x)
    ally.append(y)
    return np.vstack(allx),np.vstack(ally)
```

This is the def interp_knn ( which is the approximated nearest neighbor ANN)

```
def interp_knn(data, z, p):
    print "building kdtree"
    k = ann.kdtree(data)
    print "kdtree lookup..."
    ind, dist = k.knn(p, 1)
    print "done"
    img = z[ind[:,0]]
    img[dist[:,0] > 15] = N.NaN
    return img
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "....\read_HDF5.py", line 166, in <module>
z.ravel(), np.column_stack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel())))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 296, in column_stack
return _nx.concatenate(arrays,1)
MemoryError
```

So is the column stack giving me this error? If that is the problem, what should I do to solve it? Please give me some light.

---

EDIT:

I typed these lines to print out each value

```
print "x:",x
print "x.shape:",x.shape
print "y:",y
print "y.shape:",y.shape
print "X:",X
print "X.shape",X.shape
print "Y:",Y
print "Y.shape",Y.shape
print "x0:",x0    
print "xn:",xn    
print "y0:",y0    
print "yn:",yn
```

and I got these reult:

```
x: [[ 10424.20322635  10454.76060099  10485.45730949 ..., -12968.67726035
-12685.76602721 -12375.06502138]
[ 10382.59291927  10412.4034849   10442.35640928 ..., -12992.35321415
-12700.8632597  -12380.48805381]
[ 10340.74366218  10369.79366321  10398.98895233 ..., -13017.45507334
-12716.86098332 -12386.19350493]
..., 
[  5327.05493943   5275.15394042   5223.90854331 ...,   1918.57476975
1821.32106295   1717.34665908]
[  5303.06157859   5251.14693111   5199.89936454 ...,   1914.50352498
1818.19581363   1715.23546366]
[  5280.12577523   5226.55972784   5176.11746996 ...,   1910.4792526
1815.09866674   1714.77978295]]
x.shape: (135, 90)
y: [[ 8049.59989276  8099.28303285  8147.42741851 ...,  9925.58168202
9933.46845934  9937.89861612]
[ 8056.91586464  8106.78261584  8155.11136874 ...,  9953.01973235
9961.14109569  9965.68870206]
[ 8064.04624932  8114.09204498  8162.60060337 ...,  9980.50394667
9988.87543224  9993.54921283]
..., 
[ 7258.03197692  7292.42166577  7325.40914928 ...,  8225.26655004
8228.18675519  8230.16218915]
[ 7242.59306102  7276.75919255  7309.52794297 ...,  8201.49165135
8204.39528226  8206.36728948]
[ 7226.54007095  7261.56601577  7293.59601515 ...,  8177.75663252
8180.64399766  8182.58727191]]
y.shape: (135, 90)
X: [[-14149 -14148 -14147 ...,  14166  14167  14168]
[-14149 -14148 -14147 ...,  14166  14167  14168]
[-14149 -14148 -14147 ...,  14166  14167  14168]
..., 
[-14149 -14148 -14147 ...,  14166  14167  14168]
[-14149 -14148 -14147 ...,  14166  14167  14168]
[-14149 -14148 -14147 ...,  14166  14167  14168]]
X.shape (3635, 28318)
Y: [[ 7227  7227  7227 ...,  7227  7227  7227]
[ 7228  7228  7228 ...,  7228  7228  7228]
[ 7229  7229  7229 ...,  7229  7229  7229]
..., 
[10859 10859 10859 ..., 10859 10859 10859]
[10860 10860 10860 ..., 10860 10860 10860]
[10861 10861 10861 ..., 10861 10861 10861]]
Y.shape (3635, 28318)
x0: -14149
xn: 14168
y0: 7227
yn: 10861
```

Comment: yeah, the X and Y seems huge...  Shouldn't these be the x,y locations for which you want the interpolated values?  Do you really need that many points?  I read your other Qs, and you seems to try to overlay the data onto map.  The original data seems to be ~50km resolution, so going any finer doesnt make much sense.  what if you say arange(x0,xn+1,50), for example?  Also, ncol and nrow, they seems to me the # for the point you sample (i.e., shape of X or Y).  Hope also brofred be your help, as he knows more about this interpolation deal.

Comment: edited my solution to include what I would do.  let me know if this work, as i cannot fully test because i dont have test data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with yosukesabai that you should print out x and y, but I think you also make things a bit harder than it has to. I might not understand the code, but it seems like you are converting all the lat-lon coordinates to km and then convert the lat-lon vectors from get_lat_lon to a matrix and then back to vectors. I don't think you need to do that, at least not for the  standard scipy kdtree function.

Here is a class that converts the positions in a lat-lon vector to the corresponding i,j positions in a grid with where the grid cells have their positions defined by lat-lon matrices. This seems to be what you want.

The function ll22ij is called with lat-lon vectors corresponding to your data. You can then use the returned i-j pairs to look up values in the image with img_matrix[ivec,jvec].

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from scipy.spatial import KDTree, cKDTree

import pycdf
from pyhdf.SD import SD,SDC

class SCB:
    def __init__(self, datadir="/projData/jplSCB/ROMS/",ijarea=[],
             lat1=None,lat2=None,lon1=None,lon2=None):
        self.i1 = 0     #
        self.i2 = 111   # Size of the grid.
        self.j1 = 0     # 
        self.j2 = 211   #
        self.datadir = datadir
        g = SD(datadir + '/scb_das_grid.nc', SDC.READ)
        self.lat = g.select('lat')[:]
        self.lon = g.select('lon')[:]-360
        self.llon,self.llat = np.meshgrid(self.lon,self.lat)

    def add_ij(self):
        i1=self.i1; i2=self.i2;j1=self.j1; j2=self.j2
        self.jmat,self.imat = np.meshgrid(np.arange(self.j2-self.j1),
                                          np.arange(self.i2-self.i1))
        self.ijvec = np.vstack((np.ravel(self.imat),np.ravel(self.jmat))).T

    def add_kd(self):
        self.kd = cKDTree(list(np.vstack((np.ravel(self.llon),
                                          np.ravel(self.llat))).T))
    def ll2ij(self,lon,lat,nei=1):
        if not hasattr(self,'kd'):
            self.add_kd()
            self.add_ij()
        dist,ij = self.kd.query(list(np.vstack((lon,lat)).T),nei)
        return self.ijvec[ij][:,0],self.ijvec[ij][:,1]
```

The reason for the if stamens for add_kd and add_ij is that it is costly to generate the kd-instance for large matrices. I only generate it once and then reuse it for different datasets. the basic concept is a follows:

1. add_kd: cKDTree (or KDTree) is initiated with a long list of lat-long pairs (one pair for each grid cell). These pairs are generate by flattening the lat and lon matrices.
2. add_ij: Two matrices with consisting of i- and j positions are flattened in the same fashion as the lat and lon matrices.
3. the vectors with lat and lon values for the observations are sent to the kd.query function, and a vector with the positions of the closest pairs are returned.

Let's assume the following grid, consisting of three matrices: lat, lon positions, and data:

```
---Lon---       ---Lat---    ---Data---   
12 13 14        30 30 30     5  8  3 
12 13 14        29 29 29     6  9  7
12 13 14        28 28 28     1  2  4
```

We have observations at the following lat-lon location:

```
obs1: 12.2; 29.1
obs2: 13.4; 28.7
```

cKDtree would be initiated with the following lat-lon pairs:

```
12 28
13 28
14 28
12 29
13 29
14 29
12 30
13 30 
14 30
```

and the corresponding ij pairs would be

```
0  0
1  0
2  0
0  1
1  1
2  1
0  2
1  2
2  2
```

kd.query would return

3 and 4,

which is the positions for the grid lat-lon pairs that are closest to the positions of the observations. Those positions are also the same in the i-j pairs, which leads to:

```
---Obs---         Grid
12.2; 29.1   ->   i=0, j=1
13.4; 28.7   ->   i=1, j=1
```

Since the grid has the the following values:

```
       5 8 3
vals = 6 9 7
       1 2 4
```

You can now use vals[ivec,jvec] where ivec=[0,1] and jvec=[1,1] to get the grid values that closest corresponds to the observations.
ivec and jvec is the output from ll2ij.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this: So by using your code, I created a grid with i,j corresponding to the lat and lon. But then I don't understand how the function "ll2ij" work. Can you please explain to me?

Comment: Also, the reason for your memory error is that your code creates a couple of enormous arrays. You won't need them with my method...

Comment: Now I understood Those enormous arrays gave me the memory error. I spent some time looking your method but still got some confusions:  1.) What are self.i1, self.i2, self.j1 and self.j2 correspond to? Because I saw you made them as 0,111,0,211. (My hdf file has lat as 135 and lon as 90.)  2.) For the cKDtree, wouldn't it be initiated as: 12 13 14 12 13 14 12 13 14       30 30 30 29 29 29 28 28 28 , then by vstack, it becomes 12 13 14 12 13 14 30 30 30 29 29 29 28 28 28 ? (Because I want to make sure I know what the code does.)

Comment: 3.) And for the corresponding ij pairs, is there also like a grid that consisting of three matrices: i, j positions and data? Is the data matrix has no value at all?   Thank you. I am learning as much as I can.

Comment: 1) Yep, 111,211 corresponds to your 135,90. I did it this way to facilitate for cases when you only work with a part of the original grid. 2). I was lazy when writing out the vectors, they should be vertical.

Comment: 3) The final ij pairs represent the positions for your observations in the data matrix. Is this what you are asking about

Comment: I see. So the kd.query in your code is like the search function for the nearest point in the lat-lon pairs to the observation point (12.2, 29.1  and 13.4, 28.7)?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that x0, xn, y0, yn are projected coordinate in kilometers.  you then constructed X and Y using meshgrid with arange(x0,xn+1), arange(y0,yn+1).  each of these arange has implict assumption of 1km resolution, as step size of arange is 1 unless you specify otherwise.  Is this what you want?  It could be a huge array, e.g. if i cover one continent at 1km resolution.

so i suggest reality check printing x, y and X, Y, see if they look reasonable.

**EDIT**

After looking at what x,y are and some reading of your other Qs plus library you used, i came up with following version.  I cannot test because i dont have the modis data.  So let me know if this doesnt work, i am going to withdraw what i write here in that case.  Try this while you wait for brorfred's solution to work for you.

```
if __name__=="__main__":

    filename = ... ( the hdf file I have)
    cumData, z = readAIRS_L1_VIS(filename)

    x, y = get_lat_lon(filename)

    # extent that satellite data covers
    x0, xn = x.min(), x.max()
    y0, yn = y.min(), y.max()

    # center point of data
    xo, yo = .5 * (x0+xn), .5*(y0+yn)

    # resolution of output grid, in km
    resolution = 20

    # ncol/nrow of image array
    ncol = int((xn - x0) / resolution) + 1
    nrow = int((yn - y0) / resolution) + 1

    # lower left corner of image array on projected coord
    p0 = xo - resolution * (ncol-1) * .5
    q0 = yo - resolution * (nrow-1) * .5

    # x,y coordinate of colomns and rows of image array on proj coord
    p = p0 + np.arange(ncol) * resolution
    q = q0 + np.arange(nrow) * resolution

    # x,y coordiate of all grid point of image array on projected coord
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(p, q)

    img = interp_knn(np.column_stack((x.ravel(), y.ravel())),
            z.ravel(), np.column_stack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel())))
    img.shape = (nrow, ncol)
```

Comment: If z is my data in an array, x and y correspond to my lat and lon. Now I am creating a grid by using meshgrid. Do you have any idea how I can put the correct data point(z in this case) to the right place in the grid like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hurricane_Felix_AIRS.jpg

Comment: i edited my answer to your [Q for visualization part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948510/using-pcolor-to-plot-3-arrays-in-python/7950339#7950339), as answer won't fit into comment, and thought related more to that Q.